# Issues with LaTeX table

Tags: tables, longtable

I'm creating a formula table with distributions I've learnt in my courses of Probability and Statistics, so I was making a table and this is my code.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,booktabs,inputenc,amsmath,amssymb,multirow,graphicx,longtable}
\title{Distribuciones Discretas y Continuas}
\author{Carlos V. Ramírez Ibáñez}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}{Distribución}
      & Función de Probabilidad
      & Función de Distribución Acumulada
      & Esperanza
      & Varianza
      \\
      & $f(x)=P(X=x)$
      & $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$
      & $E(X)$
      & $Var(X)$
      \\\midrule
      
      %Unif Discreta
      $X\sim \text{Unif}\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n},\quad x=x_1,...,x_n$ 
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0,             & x<x_1 \\
         \frac{i-1}{n}, & x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i,\quad \forall\;i\in\{2,...,n\}\\
         1,             & x\geq 1
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-E(X)\right)^{2}$ 
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Bernoulli
      $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$
      & $\displaystyle p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x},\quad x=0,1$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,    &    x<0 \\ 
         1-p,   &    0\leq x<1\\
         1,     &    x\geq 1
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $p$
      & $p(1-p)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Binomial
      $X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$
      & $\displaystyle\binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x},\quad x=0,1,...,n$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k},&0\leq x<n \\
         1, & x>n
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $np$
      & $np(1-p)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Geométrica
      $X\sim\text{Geométrica}(p)$ 
      & $\displaystyle p(1-p)^{x-1}, \quad x=1,2,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=1}^{x}p(1-p)^{k-1},     &    x\geq 0
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{p}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1-p}{p^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Bin Neg
      $X\sim\text{BN}(r,p)$
      & $\displaystyle\binom{x-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r},\quad x=r,r+1,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=r}^{x}\binom{k-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{k-r},     &    x\geq r
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{r}{p}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{r(1-p)}{p^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Hipergeométrica
      $X\sim\text{HG}(N,n,r)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{r}{x}\binom{N-r}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}},\quad x=0,1,...,\min\{r,n\}$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x}\frac{\binom{r}{i}\binom{N-r}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}},     &    0\leq x\leq\min\{r,n\} \\
         1, & x>\min\{r,n\}
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{nr}{N}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{nr}{N}\left(\frac{N-r}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$
      \\[.3in]
      
      %Poisson
      $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!},\quad x=0,1,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!},     &    x\geq 0\\
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\lambda$
      & $\lambda$
      \\[.2in]\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth]{
    \begin{tabular}{ccccc}\toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}{Distribución}
      & Función de Probabilidad
      & Función de Distribución Acumulada
      & Esperanza
      & Varianza
      \\
      & $f(x)=P(X=x)$
      & $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$
      & $E(X)$
      & $Var(X)$
      \\\midrule
      
      %Normal
      $X\sim\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\;dy$
      & $\mu$
      & $\sigma^{2}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Unif Continua
      $X\sim\text{Unif}(a,b)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b-a},\quad x\in(a,b)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{x-a}{b-a}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{2}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{(b-a)^{2}}{12}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Exponencial
      $X\sim\text{Exponencial}(\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle 1-e^{-\lambda x}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Gamma
      \multirow{2}{*}{$X\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$} 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\;\frac{\lambda(\lambda y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\;dy$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\lambda^{2}}$}
      \\[.2in]
      & con $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\;dx$
      &   
      & 
      &
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Beta
      \multirow{2}{*}{$X\sim\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)$} 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)},\quad 0\leq x\leq 1$
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\;\frac{y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)}\;dy$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^{2}(\alpha+\beta+1)}$}
      \\[.2in]
      & con 
       $\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\;dx$
      &
      &
      &
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Pareto
      $X\sim\text{Pareto}(\alpha,\beta)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}},\quad \beta\leq x$
      & $\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac{\beta}{x}\right)^{\alpha}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta^{2}}{(\alpha-1)^{2}(\alpha-2)},\quad\alpha>2$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Weibull
      $X\sim\text{Weibull}(\alpha,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\alpha\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $1-e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda}\;\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\left[\Gamma\left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)-\left[\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\right]^{2}\right]$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Lognormal
      $X\sim\text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma x\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma y\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\;dy$
      & $\displaystyle e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}}$
      & $\displaystyle e^{2\mu +\sigma^{2}}\left(e^{\sigma^{2}}-1\right)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Logística
      $X\sim\text{Logística}(\alpha,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}}{\lambda\left(1+e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}\right)^{2}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}}$
      & $\displaystyle\alpha$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{2}\pi^{2}}{3}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Erlang
      $X\sim\text{Erlang}(n,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;x^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}\;dy$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{n}{\lambda}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{n}{\lambda^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

What I get is show in the picture below

[image]

What I want is to use `longtable` instead of `tabular` because it's too long a table. However, this modification does not work. Before adding `\makebox[\textwidth]`

```
\makebox[\textwidth]
{
    \begin{tabular}
CONTENIDO DE MI TABLA 
    \end{tabular}
}
```

And with `longtable` my table was off margins. Instead of being centered as I wanted, it was right-aligned. How do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: TeX.SE usually requires you to ask in English. ¿Me dejas ponerlo en inglés por alguien puede ayudarte? 

Comment: Claro, gracias!

Comment: Will there be an English translation as well?

Comment: @albert I've just added lines of translation of English so users can help (tables in LaTeX aren't my cup of tea). Long story short, Carlos wants to use a centered longtable

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you place all columns in automatic displaystyle math mode; this will save you from having to write lots and lots of `$` characters. Also, use the `dcases` environment (provided by the `mathtools` package) instead of the home-brewed `array` environments. I would also left-align the columns.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows of the `longtable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry,booktabs,mathtools,amssymb,
            longtable,array}
\geometry{a4paper,margin=2cm}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}


\title{Distribuciones Discretas y Continuas}
\author{Carlos V. Ramírez Ibáñez}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{longtable}{@{}LLLLL@{}}
      \toprule
        \text{Distribución}
      & \text{Función de Probabilidad}
      & \text{Función de Distribución Acumulada}
      & \text{Esperanza}
      & \text{Varianza}
      \\ \addlinespace
      & f(x)=P(X=x)
      & F(x)=P(X\leq x)
      & \mathrm{E}(X)
      & \mathrm{Var}(X)
      \\
      \midrule
      \endhead
      
      \addlinespace
      \midrule
      \multicolumn{5}{r@{}}{\footnotesize continúa en la página siguiente}
      \endfoot
      
      \addlinespace
      \bottomrule
      \endlastfoot
      
      \addlinespace
      %Unif Discreta
      X\sim \text{Unif}\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}
      & \frac{1}{n},\quad x=x_1,\dots,x_n 
      & \begin{dcases}
         0,             & x<x_1 \\
         \frac{i-1}{n}, & x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i,\  
         \forall\;i\in\{2,\dots,n\}\\
         1,             & x\geq 1
      \end{dcases}
      & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i 
      & \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-E(X)\right)^{2} 
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Bernoulli
      X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)
      &  p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x},\quad x=0,1
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,    &    x<0 \\ 
         1-p,   &    0\leq x<1\\
         1,     &    x\geq 1
      \end{dcases}
      & p
      & p(1-p)
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Binomial
      X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)
      & \binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x},\quad x=0,1,\dots,n
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum_{k=0}^{x}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k},&0\leq x<n \\
         1, & x>n
      \end{dcases}
      & np
      & np(1-p)
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Geométrica
      X\sim\text{Geométrica}(p) 
      &  p(1-p)^{x-1}, \quad x=1,2,\dots
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,                             &    x<0 \\
         \sum_{k=1}^{x}p(1-p)^{k-1},     &    x\geq 0
        \end{dcases}
      & \frac{1}{p}
      & \frac{1-p}{p^{2}}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Bin Neg
      X\sim\text{BN}(r,p)
      & \binom{x-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r},\quad x=r,r+1,\dots
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum_{k=r}^{x}\binom{k-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{k-r},     &    x\geq r
        \end{dcases}
      & \frac{r}{p}
      & \frac{r(1-p)}{p^{2}}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Hipergeométrica
      X\sim\text{HG}(N,n,r) 
      & \frac{\binom{r}{x}\binom{N-r}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}},\quad x=0,1,\dots,\min\{r,n\}
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum_{i=0}^{x}\frac{\binom{r}{i}\binom{N-r}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}},     &    0\leq x\leq\min\{r,n\} \\
         1, & x>\min\{r,n\}
        \end{dcases}
      & \frac{nr}{N}
      & \frac{nr}{N}\left(\frac{N-r}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Poisson
      X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)
      & \frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!},\quad x=0,1,\dots
      & \begin{dcases}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!},     &    x\geq 0\\
        \end{dcases}
      & \lambda
      & \lambda
      \\ \addlinespace

      %Normal
      X\sim\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^{2})
      & \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R} 
      & \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\,dy
      & \mu
      & \sigma^{2}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Unif Continua
      X\sim\text{Unif}(a,b) 
      & \frac{1}{b-a},\quad x\in(a,b)
      & \frac{x-a}{b-a}
      & \frac{a+b}{2}
      & \frac{(b-a)^{2}}{12}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución Exponencial
      X\sim\text{Exponencial}(\lambda) 
      & \lambda e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
      &  1-e^{-\lambda x}
      & \frac{1}{\lambda}
      & \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución Gamma
        X\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)
      & \frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
      & \int_{0}^{x}\;\frac{\lambda(\lambda y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,dy
      & \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}
      & \frac{\alpha}{\lambda^{2}}
      \\ \addlinespace
      & con \Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\;dx
      &   
      & 
      &
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución Beta
        X\sim\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)
      & \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)},\quad 0\leq x\leq 1
      & \int_{0}^{x}\;\frac{y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)}\,dy
      & \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}
      & \frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^{2}(\alpha+\beta+1)}
      \\ \addlinespace
      & con 
       \text{B}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\;dx
      &
      &
      &
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución de Pareto
      X\sim\text{Pareto}(\alpha,\beta) 
      & \frac{\alpha\beta^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}},\quad \beta\leq x
      &  1-\left(\frac{\beta}{x}\right)^{\alpha}
      & \frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}
      & \frac{\alpha\beta^{2}}{(\alpha-1)^{2}(\alpha-2)},\quad\alpha>2
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución de Weibull
      X\sim\text{Weibull}(\alpha,\lambda) 
      & \alpha\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
      & 1-e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}}
      & \frac{1}{\lambda}\;\Gamma\biggl(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\biggr)
      & \frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\biggl\{ \Gamma\biggl(1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\biggr)-\biggl[\Gamma\biggl(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\biggr)\biggr]^{2}\,\biggr\}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución Lognormal
      X\sim\text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma) 
      & \frac{1}{\sigma x\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
      & \int_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma y\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\,dy
      &  e^{\mu+\sigma^{2}/2}
      &  e^{2\mu +\sigma^{2}}\Bigl(e^{\sigma^2}-1\Bigr)
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución Logística
      X\sim\text{Logística}(\alpha,\lambda) 
      & \frac{e^{-(x-\alpha)/\lambda}}{\lambda\left(1+e^{-(x-\alpha)/\lambda}\right)^{2}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}
      & \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x-\alpha)/\lambda}}
      & \alpha
      & \frac{\lambda^{2}\pi^{2}}{3}
      \\ \addlinespace
      
      %Distribución de Erlang
      X\sim\text{Erlang}(n,\lambda) 
      & \frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;x^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}
      & \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}\,dy
      & \frac{n}{\lambda}
      & \frac{n}{\lambda^{2}}
      \\ \addlinespace
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following might serve as a place to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\title{Distribuciones Discretas y Continuas}
\author{Carlos V. Ramírez Ibáñez}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
    \begin{longtable}{ccccc}
    \toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}{Distribución}
      & Función de Probabilidad
      & Función de Distribución Acumulada
      & Esperanza
      & Varianza
      \\
      \endhead
      \bottomrule
      \endfoot
      & $f(x)=P(X=x)$
      & $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$
      & $E(X)$
      & $Var(X)$
      \\\midrule
      
      %Unif Discreta
      $X\sim \text{Unif}\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n},\quad x=x_1,...,x_n$ 
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0,             & x<x_1 \\
         \frac{i-1}{n}, & x_{i-1}\leq x\leq x_i,\quad \forall\;i\in\{2,...,n\}\\
         1,             & x\geq 1
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-E(X)\right)^{2}$ 
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Bernoulli
      $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(p)$
      & $\displaystyle p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x},\quad x=0,1$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,    &    x<0 \\ 
         1-p,   &    0\leq x<1\\
         1,     &    x\geq 1
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $p$
      & $p(1-p)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Binomial
      $X\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$
      & $\displaystyle\binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x},\quad x=0,1,...,n$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}\binom{n}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k},&0\leq x<n \\
         1, & x>n
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $np$
      & $np(1-p)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Geométrica
      $X\sim\text{Geométrica}(p)$ 
      & $\displaystyle p(1-p)^{x-1}, \quad x=1,2,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=1}^{x}p(1-p)^{k-1},     &    x\geq 0
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{p}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1-p}{p^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Bin Neg
      $X\sim\text{BN}(r,p)$
      & $\displaystyle\binom{x-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r},\quad x=r,r+1,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=r}^{x}\binom{k-1}{r-1}p^{r}(1-p)^{k-r},     &    x\geq r
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{r}{p}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{r(1-p)}{p^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Hipergeométrica
      $X\sim\text{HG}(N,n,r)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\binom{r}{x}\binom{N-r}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}},\quad x=0,1,...,\min\{r,n\}$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{i=0}^{x}\frac{\binom{r}{i}\binom{N-r}{n-i}}{\binom{N}{n}},     &    0\leq x\leq\min\{r,n\} \\
         1, & x>\min\{r,n\}
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{nr}{N}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{nr}{N}\left(\frac{N-r}{N}\right)\left(\frac{N-n}{N-1}\right)$
      \\[.3in]
      
      %Poisson
      $X\sim\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{x}e^{-\lambda}}{x!},\quad x=0,1,...$
      & $\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
         0 ,                                    &    x<0 \\
         \sum\limits_{k=0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{k}e^{-\lambda}}{k!},     &    x\geq 0\\
      \end{array}\right.$
      & $\lambda$
      & $\lambda$
      \\[.2in]
      & $f(x)=P(X=x)$
      & $F(x)=P(X\leq x)$
      & $E(X)$
      & $Var(X)$
      \\\midrule
      
      %Normal
      $X\sim\text{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\;dy$
      & $\mu$
      & $\sigma^{2}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Unif Continua
      $X\sim\text{Unif}(a,b)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b-a},\quad x\in(a,b)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{x-a}{b-a}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{a+b}{2}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{(b-a)^{2}}{12}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Exponencial
      $X\sim\text{Exponencial}(\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\lambda e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle 1-e^{-\lambda x}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Gamma
      \multirow{2}{*}{$X\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$} 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\;\frac{\lambda(\lambda y)^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\;dy$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\lambda^{2}}$}
      \\[.2in]
      & con $\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\;dx$
      &   
      & 
      &
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Beta
      \multirow{2}{*}{$X\sim\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)$} 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)},\quad 0\leq x\leq 1$
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\;\frac{y^{\alpha-1}(1-y)^{\beta-1}}{\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)}\;dy$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$}
      & \multirow{2}{*}{$\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{(\alpha+\beta)^{2}(\alpha+\beta+1)}$}
      \\[.2in]
      & con 
       $\text{B}(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}\;dx$
      &
      &
      &
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Pareto
      $X\sim\text{Pareto}(\alpha,\beta)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta^{\alpha}}{x^{\alpha+1}},\quad \beta\leq x$
      & $\displaystyle 1-\left(\frac{\beta}{x}\right)^{\alpha}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta}{\alpha-1}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\alpha\beta^{2}}{(\alpha-1)^{2}(\alpha-2)},\quad\alpha>2$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Weibull
      $X\sim\text{Weibull}(\alpha,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\alpha\lambda(\lambda x)^{\alpha-1}e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $1-e^{-(\lambda x)^{\alpha}}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda}\;\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\left[\Gamma\left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha}\right)-\left[\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)\right]^{2}\right]$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Lognormal
      $X\sim\text{Lognormal}(\mu,\sigma)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma x\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\frac{1}{\sigma y\sqrt{2\pi}}\;e^{-\frac{(\ln y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^{2}}}\;dy$
      & $\displaystyle e^{\mu+\frac{\sigma^{2}}{2}}$
      & $\displaystyle e^{2\mu +\sigma^{2}}\left(e^{\sigma^{2}}-1\right)$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución Logística
      $X\sim\text{Logística}(\alpha,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}}{\lambda\left(1+e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}\right)^{2}},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1+e^{-\frac{(x-\alpha)}{\lambda}}}$
      & $\displaystyle\alpha$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{2}\pi^{2}}{3}$
      \\[.2in]
      
      %Distribución de Erlang
      $X\sim\text{Erlang}(n,\lambda)$ 
      & $\displaystyle\frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;x^{n-1}e^{-\lambda x},\quad x\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$
      & $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{x}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{(n-1)!}\;y^{n-1}e^{-\lambda y}\;dy$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{n}{\lambda}$
      & $\displaystyle\frac{n}{\lambda^{2}}$
      \\[.2in]
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```